# JSON with dynamic Root-Object

Tags: c#, rest

problably I'm not experienced enought and my question is kind of dumb:
For learning purposes I'm trying to connect to a REST-Service, which delivers JSON-Data.

From what I've learned, the purpose of JSON is to deliver the same data to any possible client without having a State of itself.

My code is looking like this:

```
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("SomeUrl"));

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // List data response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("").Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Task<Stream> readTask = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            readTask.ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
                using (Stream result = task.Result)
                {
                    result.Position = 0;
                    RootObject obj = (RootObject)ser.ReadObject(result);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }

    }


    public class Sum
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int profileIconId { get; set; }
        public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
        public long revisionDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Sum khalgor { get; set; }
    }
```

But here's my Problem: I've created this classes "Sum" and "RootObject" by using the Website http://json2csharp.com/, the JSON-String is looking like this:

```
{"khalgor":{"id":23801741,"name":"Khalgor","profileIconId":7,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1396876104000}}
```

The Problem: The Name "Khalgor" seems to be used as a Root-Object, but it's a Name. So if I'd like to user for another Name, I'd have to user another RootObject.

It does not make that much sense to create such a Structure, so my question: What's the best practice here? Do I map this RootObject/Property to another object manually? Do I use some Reflection to dynamically create an Property or rename it?

As usual, thanks a lot for all Responses

Matthias

Edit:

I tinkered arround a bit and that's my first idea of a solution:

```
public static class LOLObjectFactory
{
    public static ILOLObject Create(string jsonString)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<String, object> entry = (jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString) as Dictionary<string, object>).First().Value as Dictionary<String, object>;

        Type selectedType = null;

        List<string> fieldNames = entry.Select(f => f.Key).OrderBy(f => f).ToList();

        Type[] types = typeof(ILOLObject).Assembly.GetTypes();
        foreach(var type in types)
        {
            List<string> typeProperties =  type.GetProperties().Select(f => f.Name).OrderBy(f => f).ToList();

            if (fieldNames.SequenceEqual(typeProperties) && typeof(ILOLObject).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                selectedType = type;
                break;
            }
        }

        ILOLObject result = System.Activator.CreateInstance(selectedType) as ILOLObject;
        foreach(var prop in result.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            prop.SetValue(result, entry.First(f => f.Key == prop.Name).Value);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

So all the objects I have have the ILOLObject implemented. I'm sure it's not working for everything, but I guess that would be a good approach?

Edit2: Just by looking at it I see I'll have a lot of work to do, but I think the idea behind it is quite clear.

Comment: Purpose of Json is to wrap data into string representation for transporting purposes. What you refer with stateless applies to REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore the root altogether (e.g. it changes its name everytime) use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to parse it into an object and ignore the topmost element. Example:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
if (obj != null)
{
    var root = obj.First;
    if (root != null)
    {
        var sumJson = root.First;
        if (sumJson != null)
        {
            var sum = sumJson.ToObject<Sum>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? I changed into
    public Sum testProp { get; set; }

And now it's always null. It seems like it exactly needs "khalgor". Can I use something like the DataMember Attribute?

I'd really like to have no RootObject, since I just want the Data in the "khalgor" property.

Comment: If you parse Json into your objects and the root is not named testProp in the Json text then ofcourse it will not be mapped to your object. So your question basically is how to ignore the root?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller see me updated answer. I think thats what you want. It will ignore the name of the root element and extract one nested sum element of it.

Comment: Hi BlueM, thanks alot, I was hoping to avoid such shenanigans. I can't understand why someone implements JSON like this and returns an Name as Root.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet for json "fragments" is to deserialize into a dynamic object:

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(inputData);
```

Then you can deserialize parts that make sense into proper .NET objects.

```
SomeObject o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeObject>(stuff["someProperty"].ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no easy way to say something like: "Screw RootObject, and screw the property "khalgor", just get me the Data!" ?